# How to reverse the movement of the mouse on the X and Y axes?

Tags: game-maker, mouse

I would like to know, how to do so that when moving the mouse to the right, it would go to the left and vice versa.

I looked for something related on the gamemaker page, but I didn't find what I'm looking for.

**LINK:**

https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/mouse,%20keyboard%20and%20other%20controls/mouse%20input/index.html

Comment: Where do you currently use the mouse inputs in your code?

Comment: If I understand the question, I still don't use it at all. I just wanted to change the movement.

Comment: Does that mean you're currently using a built-in cursor? Have you considered hiding the built-in cursor, and animating your own using the mouse information described at the link you provided?

Comment: Yes, I thought about creating an object and putting mouse properties on it. But I think it would be simpler if there was a way to change the movement of the cursor itself. I thought this based on FPS games, or third person games, which invert the position of the mouse. So, I thought there would be a simple way to do the same in the gamemaker.

Comment: What they're inverting is the movement of a game object, not the cursor itself.

Comment: The rotation of a camera axis, right?